# Database self-hosting

Tags: php, mysql, database, server

I want to create a website where the users can have their own database. An example:
- An user will receive some data from HTTP POST and I want to store all the information into a local database to access to it. For example, the URL that the user has visited in the last month.

I know that the best option will be to create a database in my server and put each user in it, but it will be very long database and the information between users is not shared, therefore it will be more secure using a local database, but I don´t know if that can be done. Even there are not a login screen to save the user details to log in.

My project is about ESP8266 and uploading data to a server, so this can be done using a microcontroller instead the computer. I have seen the raspberry to use it as a server and the database will be stored there , but it is so expensive. Can be done using another board as Arduino, Texas Instruments, etc...

The question is if I can host a database in user side. Using PHP, HTML,... scripts. I only know how to do it using a computer or other server, but I only want to know if this it's possible.

I post here because maybe can be done in HTML, PHP or something like that, but I think this cannot be done, so I will post also in the arduino forum.

Comment: use 1 database. If you can't make 1 database secure, you can't make n databases secure

Comment: The question is if I can host a database in user side. Using PHP, HTML,... scripts. I only know how to do it using a computer or other server, but I only want to know if this it's possible.

Comment: sure, look into [html5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). If you are asking whether or not a random user accesses your website, and a local to user on their box mysql daemon will pop into existence that your PHP can address, good luck with that one

Comment: But It could be displayed even after close the website and reopen? I mean, I store a data into local storage, then I shutdown my computer and then I open again the website. Will the previous data still available? I'm going to search for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host a database using a browser.
WebSQL is a local database used in javascript and localStorage is not a SQL database but it is also a database.

**BUT** this is far away from secure and you should only do it if the info you're gonna store is not sensible like you said 'the page user visited last month'.

http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: WebSQL databases are only accessible to the browser, and even then only when your web page is open. They are not accessible from outside the browser (e.g, from a microcontroller), and as such don't appear to be a solution to this problem at all.

Comment: He's not asking for a solution only accessible from a microcontroller. If he wants to do it with 'PHP and HTML' this is the way. AND also, it IS possible to access a url using a microcontroller/arduino board/. More attention to the post, please, not to a single quote.